# Evaluating the chi-square integral

Tags: integration, statistics, chi-squared, cumulative-distribution-functions

The question is to find that value of x for which F(x)=0.3, where X follows Chi-square distribution with 13 df.

∫_0^x▒〖(e^((-x)/2)   x^(n/2-1))/(2^(n/2)   ⌈n/2┤ )=0.3〗

∫_0^x▒〖e^((-x)/2)  x^(13/2-1 )=0.3*  2^(13/2)* ⌈13/2┤  〗

I cannot move further. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please format using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is solved using the chi-squared tables

$$x\approx 9.93$$

---

Usually Paper Tables do not show $F(0.3)$. In a standard chi-square table you usually find $F(0.25)$ and $F(0.5)$ but with a simple gaussian approx you get

$$u_{0.3}=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[z_{0.3}+\sqrt{2\times 13-1}\Bigg]^2=\frac{1}{2}\Big[-0.53+5\Big]^2\approx 9.99$$

Which is very close to the exact result of $9.93$ that I got with a calculator